# Getting a string in a specific tag with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I try to get all the titles from a website `https://webscraper.io/test-sites`. For that I use Beautiful Soup. The title (in this case E-commerce site) is always included in the following part of a code:

```
<h2 class="site-heading">
    <a href="/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone">
        E-commerce site
    </a>
</h2>
```

I don't get that part. I already tried different things but for example the most intuitive code for me is not working:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://webscraper.io/test-sites'
r = requests.get(url)
r_html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r_html)
string = soup.find_all("h2", string=re.compile("E-commerce")
```

How can I get just the title, in this case 'E-commerce site' for a list?

Comment: What are you getting instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. A few issues.

- You are not using any parser to parse `r_html`. I have used `html.parser` here.
- I don't see any need to use Regex `re` in your problem.
- The titles are present inside `h2` tags with class name - `site-heading`. You can select them.

This code selects all the titles and prints them.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://webscraper.io/test-sites'
r = requests.get(url)
r_html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r_html,"html.parser")
string = soup.find_all("h2", class_='site-heading')

for i in string:
    print(i.text.strip())
```

```
E-commerce site
E-commerce site with pagination links
E-commerce site with popup links
E-commerce site with AJAX pagination links
E-commerce site with "Load more" buttons
E-commerce site that loads items while scrolling
Table playground
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://webscraper.io/test-sites'
r = requests.get(url)
r_html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r_html, features="html.parser")
h2s = soup.find_all("h2")
for h2 in h2s:
    print(h2.text.strip())
```

this will give you all the texts in your H2s.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thank you I used the first answer from @Ram which was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get a list of all the titles available. You could do something like this:

```
titles = [x.getText() for x in soup.find_all("h2", {class_="site-heading"})]
```

Comment: I don't know Python well but correct code might be `soup.find_all` instead of `soup.findall` like others wrote.